# Image files after upload are larger than they should be

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am uploading (through aws-sdk library to node.js) some files to Amazon S3. When it comes to image file - it looks like it is much bigger on S3 than body.length printed in node.js
E.g. I've got file with 7050103 of body.length, but S3 browser shows that it is:
Size: 8,38 MB (8789522 bytes)
I know that there are some meta here - but what meta could take more than 1MB?

What is the source of such a big difference? Is there a way to find out what size it would be on s3 before sending this file to s3?

Comment: Try getting the file size usign s3cmd or the aws cli, or another method... interesting to see if there's a difference. Also, try downloading it and check the actual size.

Answer (score 0):

I have upload file via s3 console and actually in this case there was no difference in size. I found out that the problem was in using lwip library for rotating image. I had a bug - I did rotate even if angle was 0, so I was rotating by 0 deg. After such rotating the image was bigger. I think that compression to jpg may be in different quality or something.